# Issue showing data of 2 users being pulled from the same page in ionic/angular

Tags: ionic-framework, routes, ionic2, angular-routing

So I am currently working with ionic and angular. I am displaying 2 different types of users on a single page using ion-segment (artist and venue). The information for both users is being displayed on a card just the way I want it. When I click on the artist profile it's being displayed but when I click on the venue user it's displaying the HTML from the artist without the data.
The id of the venue profile is correct it's just when brought to the profile it's not working the way I want. I feel the issue might be in the app-routing? but I'm not sure cause I've tried changing it and it's still not working.

discover.page.html:

```
  <ion-card
  *ngFor="let venue of relevantVenue.slice(1)"
  fill="clear"
  [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab1','discover',venue.id]"
  >
```

venue-details:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if (!paramMap.has('venueId')) {
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/tabs/tab1/discover');
        return;
      }
      this.venueSub = this.venueService
      .getVenue(paramMap.get('venueId'))
      .subscribe(venue => {
        this.loadedVenue = venue;
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.venueSub) {
      this.venueSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'discover/:artistId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/artist-details/artist-details.module').then(m => m.ArtistDetailsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'discover/:venueId',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/discover/venue-details/venue-details.module').then(m => m.VenueDetailsPageModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> path: 'discover/:artistId'

> path: 'discover/:venueId'

These paths both use the same parent (parent being "discover").
Therefore there is a conflict in the routes. when it is to **discover-artist** / **discover-venue** it should work just fine.

After thats done change:

> [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab1','discover',venue.id]"

To:

> [routerLink]="['/','tabs','tab1','discover-venue',venue.id]"

and same for discover-artist

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on the artist profile it's being displayed but when I
> click on the venue user it's displaying the HTML from the artist
> without the data.

Can you show us the screen how it looks ? Try using ngif to toggle the html blocks on/off just to force the webview to retrieve the data dynamically. Also do console logs from your ts file to confirm data is actually being received.